# multithreading calling functions define in C from a tcl thread

Tags: c, multithreading, tcl

I'm trying to move some processing of a report to a different tcl thread apart from the main thread, since when a report is very long it stalls the main application, i have some C functions that i need to call from this new thread that return a variable that is need it. This is what i'm trying to do as of right now

Tcl code:

```
proc pdfthread {} \
{
  set threadID [thread::create]
  set result ""  //"getAlarmList" is the C function the rest is the parameters 
  thread::send $threadID [list getAlarmList 304 {2013-10-16 15:10:26} {2013-10-16 15:13:00}] result
  .sumRepTxt insert end "Count = $result\n"  //.sumRepTxt is just a text widget
}
```

as of right now i get invalid command name "getAlarmList"

Comment: Your answer is correct, but please don't edit your answer into the question. Post it as answer. Note: you could try to `load {} sample` (without the filename).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found a way to do it, I guess the new thread doesn't know about the C library so if I load the library where the C function is then it recognizes the command so something like this:

```
proc pdfthread {} \
{
  set threadID [thread::create { 
                     load ./samples.so
                     thread::wait}]
  set result ""
  thread::send $threadID [list getAlarmList 304 {2013-10-16 15:10:26} {2013-10-16 15:13:00}] result
  .sumRepTxt insert end "Count = $result\n"
```